# How to insert nextval to trigger inside for loop

Tags: plsql, unique-constraint, nextval, database-trigger

Here is a code for trigger and it have a for loop. When trigger is fired (INSERT OR UPDATE) there's another table data must include it is MICL_SUP

```
 OPEN  projMgrsCursor;
        LOOP
        FETCH projMgrsCursor INTO projMgr;  
        select micl_sup_id_seq.nextval into  SUPID from dual;
        insert into MICL_SUP VALUES ((SUPID), (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL),                             :NEW.ENTRYADDEDBY_EMP_NO, 3000, 0,projMgr, NULL,:NEW.EMP_NO);
       END LOOP;    

      CLOSE projMgrsCursor;
```

This is the table structure. `Sup_ID` primary and unique key . I can't make any changes to table structure

```
SUP_ID  -primary key             
ASSIGNED_DATE            
ASSIGNED_BY_EMP_NO          
AMOUNT_LIMIT            
IS_OVVERRIDDEN      
SUP_EMP_NO          
RTD_EMP     
EMP_NO
```

To enter sup_ID I use `select micl_sup_id_seq.nextval into SUPID from dual;` 
but when I run this code there's an error  `"RA-00001: unique constraint violated"` (this is not a compilation error ) Is there any other way to add `sup_ID`? Where have I gone wrong?

This question is related with this trigger [PlSQL trigger error ORA-0000 ORA-06512:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496584/plsql-trigger-error-ora-0000-ora-06512)

Comment: You can simply give a `insert into MICL_SUP VALUES ((micl_sup_id_seq.nextval), (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL), ...` in the loop itself. No need for a separate variable.

Comment: nothar is a compilation error 

 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: are you sure there's no other unique field in the table?

Comment: @Sebas yep some only  foreign keys

Comment: How was the sequence created? If it was created after the table was partially populated, was it set with a `start with` value that was higher than any existing values in the table, or did it default to `1`? Is there a trigger on the `MICL_SUP` table? Also agree that you shouldn't need to put the sequence value into a separate variable unless you need to use it more than once, so `... VALUES (micl_sup_id_seq.nextval, SYSDATE, ...)` would be cleaner - no need to select `sysdate` from dual, either.

Comment: @cHaNkX, people are trying to help you, free of charge; the least you could do is be helpful in return. Also, why is it our concern if you lose your job because of a trigger? I know it sounds harsh but you need to remember we're here to help people who help themselves, not people who demand help to do their job for them.

Comment: @AlexPoole  Hi its created as 

'CREATE SEQUENCE "c"."NewSequence"
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
 START WITH 3061
 CACHE 20;'

When I add 'VALUES (micl_sup_id_seq.nextval, SYSDATE, ...)' compilation error Occurred. dont know y :(

but thanks alot for ur help 
cheez

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Hi First of all I must say i'm a newbie to Pl/sQl , or use doing advance stuff with databases. To be honest i only used mysql form it also I never done advance stuff, i wrote every few triggers form mysql. So there are lots and lots things to I have to learn. And this is my first ever Job I got after struggling for sometime . May be its not value for u but  for me it not like that. 

As I know stackoverflow is a place which help to programmers/student  who cant find solutions.(knowlage shareing I have to say I learn lots and lots of things form stackoverflow.

Comment: Yep. We're trying to help you. But *you're not being helpful* back. That's my point. Your comments below "its not working" "but no use" "no cant do like that" are useless and are just asking us to guess what might be wrong on your side. It's a two-way street. And putting in statements like "I'll lose my job" is emotional blackmail that no-one is going to take any notice of anyway, so it just hurts your case.

Comment: Congrats on getting your first job, by the way. You may feel overwhelmed at first, but remember it's your employer's responsibility to ensure you are capable of doing the job. If they fire you just because you are having trouble with a trigger, there's bigger issues at stake. Maybe you're worrying too much?

Comment: Thanks alot 
no actully Im on my probation period so Im dead scared about evrything I'm doing .

sry i know I have done few mistakes when replying> i appreciated ur support to solve this problem .
but now I give up on this and try to change this from code level, b'coz I already pass my dead line   
**No one is born a genius, talented  or experience person , with time they get to know many stuff ** 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not including calculation of `micl_sup_id_seq.nextval` into your cursor?

```
cursor  projMgrsCursor is 
  select b.BU_MEMBER_ID, micl_sup_id_seq.nextval SUPID
  from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your code as:

```
DECLARE
  nSupid   NUMBER;
  projMgr  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  OPEN  projMgrsCursor;

  LOOP
    FETCH projMgrsCursor INTO projMgr;
    EXIT WHEN projMgrsCursor%NOTFOUND;

    select micl_sup_id_seq.nextval into nSUPID from dual;

    insert into MICL_SUP 
      (SUPID, ASSIGNED_DATE, ASSIGNED_BY_EMP_NO,   AMOUNT_LIMIT,
       IS_OVERRIDDEN, SUP_EMP_NO, RTD_EMP, EMP_NO)
    VALUES
      (nSupid, SYSDATE,  :NEW.ENTRYADDEDBY_EMP_NO, 3000,
       0,              projMgr,   NULL,    :NEW.EMP_NO);
   END LOOP;    

  CLOSE projMgrsCursor;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Successful completion');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: ' || SQLCODE || '  ' || SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: OK - I added a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` at the end of the code to indicate successful completion, and added an exception handler block to report if any exceptions are thrown.  Try adding those to your code and see what prints out.